# Using renders for textures in objects behind transparencies

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, texturing, uv, volumetrics

[image]I am trying to animate a texture using a render from the same blender file. I have tried several things so far.

I have rendered the animation independently and then add the video as an image texture. The problem is that I need the texture and composite to be rendered together.

I have used an additional scene for the texture render and an intermediate file where the renders are stored (render layer to output file, use that file for texture input). The problems are that the texture lags one frame and that I cannot link the object with the animated texture in other blend files because it also needs the render setup.

I have also tried to make a UV render layer for the object and add the texture during composition, but I have refractive objects in the way and the object appears as black in the UV mapping.

Is there any way to have the UV render layer to consider the refraction of other objects? How about a UV render layer that takes into account volumetric scattering? (e.g. adding alpha channels to the UV render and raytracing the UV coordinates).

An example application is a first person view of a biker wearing a full-head helmet and watching a CCTV

I am using Blender 2.79

Thanks

Comment: Sorry I just don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve here or the problem with your approach. Can't you render the video texture frames out first and load the correct one from disk?

Comment: Imagine a scene where a child is playing videogames on a TV and the parents are watching from outside the room through a glass window. Synchronizing armatures in two different scenes is a bit of a hell. I am also thinking in a real time implementation with Eevee in the short future, where the screen will need to be rendered in real time. Being able to apply a render layer to a texture would solve all these problems.

Comment: Actually, from what I have been trying, it seems that blender renders all render layers in the current scene first, and then the other scenes. If there was a way to fix the order of render layers, that would also solve my problem.

Comment: Why do you have to insist on certain render order for the frames? Render all frames on the other scene first, then use the correct frame from it as texture in the other scene.

Comment: Well, if I want to render the whole image in one go, its no use to render the main scene if some textures are not available.